Why should the pH change when I add sodium hydroxide to water?
I am a student and I am trying to understand the concept of pH.
If I add pure $\ce{NaOH}$ in water, it leads to the formation of $\ce{OH-}$ ions in the water. But this shouldn't lead to any change in the $\ce{H+}$ concentration in water, right? Then why should the pH change?

You are wrong to think that OH- ions formation is not affecting H+ ions. They react to make neutral molecules.

Its "pH" and not "Ph" or "ph" or "PH".

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Water can be thought of as a dissociation reaction $$\ce{H2O <-> H+ + OH-}$$
When you add in $\ce{NaOH}$, it dissociates completely into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$. This causes the equilibrium of the above reaction to shift to the left, which means more $\ce{H+}$ ions are becoming $\ce{H2O}$, which increases pH.
In a nutshell, whenever you get an alkaline with an $\ce{OH-}$ base, more $\ce{H+}$ ions get reacted, increasing the pH.
